# Redis Docker image using ACL

Tags: redis, acl

I am trying to test the new Redis 6 ACL configuration.
I want to run a test with the simplest configuration possible to get acquainted with the configuration.
My Redis will run as a Docker container. Please, consider that I am a Redis complete newbie.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM redis:6.2.1

COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
COPY users.acl /etc/redis/users.acl

EXPOSE 6379
```

My `redis.conf` file:

```
aclfile /etc/redis/users.acl
```

My `users.acl` file:

```
user test on >password ~* &* +@all
```

I am able to run a container without errors, but it seems that the container is not loading the ACL configuration: in fact, when I run `redis-cli` into the container and I execute `ACL LIST`, I get as output:

```
1) "user default on nopass ~* &* +@all"
```

which is clearly not as intended.

I fear I am missing something in the `Dockerfile`, but I cannot find a documentation suited for my needs.

Does someone have hints?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that my `Dockerfile` was missing the following last line: `CMD ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]`. Otherwise, the Redis Docker image is set to run without configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redis/redis/6.0/redis.conf) clearly stated:

```
# Redis configuration file example.
#
# Note that in order to read the configuration file, Redis must be
# started with the file path as first argument:
#
# ./redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
```

In the `Dockerfile` is missing one last line:

```
CMD ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
```

Comment: how do we do this via environment variables? no one wants to be maintaining static files all over the place