# How to set multiple passwords to a redis container version 6.2

Tags: docker, redis, passwords

I'd like to know if it's possible to set multiple passwords to a single redis container.
I can create two secrets (which are the passwords) in the redis container, but how can I specify to the database that I can login to those two passwords?

```
containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.redis.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.redis.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.redis.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.redis.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
            - name: REDIS_SECRET1
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "container1"
                  key: "REDIS_SECRET1"
            - name: REDIS_SECRET2              
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "container1"
                  key: "REDIS_SECRET2"
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - bash
              - "-c"
              - |
                redis-cli -a $REDIS_SECRET1 ping
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.redis.resources | nindent 12 }}
          args: ["--save", "''", "--requirepass", "$(REDIS_SECRET1)"]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I see that through redis-cli command line I can do it, but I don't want to run the command by hand, I wanna do it every time the pod restarts.
The command that works is:
``` redis-cli -a aaa8iua9k  ACL SETUSER default on ">password1" ~* +@all ```
Don't know how to put that command in the yaml file

Comment: try define config file? look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66884292/redis-docker-image-using-acl

Comment: I managed to add a second password by running `redis-cli -a $REDIS_SECRET1 ACL SETUSER default on ">$(REDIS_SECRET2)" ~* +@all`
And when I list the user it shows me this:
`user default on #d40cc5... #e3b0c... ~* &* +@all` but when I try to authenticate with the second password it says that the password is not available.
Any ideas?